# Updating cache automatically

Tags: azure, redis

I want to use Redis Cache. I want to store some data but it needs to be refreshed automatically at regular intervals.

If I have 100 rows and if any row has been updated in Cosmos DB, the row should get updated.

I want to know how to smoothly achieve this. Do I need to update the cache manually?

Comment: Might be duplicate with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49299958/how-would-redis-get-to-know-if-it-has-to-return-cached-data-or-fresh-data-from-d)

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know how to smoothly achieve this. Do I need to update the cache manually?

Redis has no idea if the data has been updated in somewhere else. Yes, you need to do it **manually**.

Your client/application which is updating the main-DB should also invalidate/update Redis cache(key corresponding to updated data) accordingly.