# Invalidate redis cache when database changes with Azure Logic App and Azure Function

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, redis, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

First of all:

> There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things. [See full post](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html)

In our application, we use `Redis` as an in-memory cache server. We store customer information with composite key `customer_CustomerGUID`. Our strategy is:

For example the `Customer` table.

1. We have some endpoints where we provide data from the cache (suppose `GetCustomerInformation`).
2. In our business codes, when we update customer information, we invalidate the cache value of that specific customer.

***In this way, we can serve the latest data from the cache every time we update in real-time.***

Now Problem is, the code base is growing and developers also. So new developers or any developer often forget to invalidate customer cache when update customer information and there are a lot of places from where customer information is being updated. Furthermore, invalidate cache code segment should not be in business class from the design perspective(I guess).

We thought several approaches like adding an interceptor when we call SaveChanges with EF (we use entity framework), adding `HandlerAttribute` on those endpoints which potential to change customer information or other approaches also. But none of those is convincing from a simplicity perspective.

Our whole application resides on `Azure Services`. We are deciding to use `Azure Logic Apps` and `Azure Functions` to invalidate the cache. When customer information updates `Azure Logic Apps` will call an Azure Function and that azure function will invalidate the cache of that customer.

Is this approach is good enough to implement or Is there any other good approach in our situation.

Comment: a little more code would be helpful

Comment: Can you tolerant some inconsistence between the cache and the database? Normally you don't need to update the cache when the database is changed. Instead, only update the cache when the key has been expired from the cache. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49299958) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384889).

Comment: Also, it's NOT always a good idea to immediately update the cache when the database has been changed. Since the new update might evict some popular items in the cache.

Comment: @for_stack For our situation since it is a financial app, some modifications need immediate cache invalidation. For example `block customer` or change of `CustomerStatus`.